# MongoDB calculate sum of $unwind document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Lets say I have 2 `reports` documents with an embeded `line_items` document:

#### Reports with embeded line_items

```
{
    _id: "1",
    week_number: "1",
    line_items: [
       {
           cash: "5",
           miscellaneous: "10"
       },
       {
           cash: "20",
           miscellaneous: "0"
       }
    ]
},
{
    _id: "2",
    week_number: "2",
    line_items: [
       {
           cash: "100",
           miscellaneous: "0"
       },
       {
           cash: "10",
           miscellaneous: "0"
       }
    ]
}
```

What I need to do is perform a set of additions on each line_item (in this case cash + miscellaneous) and have the grand total set on the reports query as a 'gross' field. I would like to end up with the following result:

#### Desired result

```
{ _id: "1", week_number: "1", gross: "35" },{ _id: "2", week_number: "2", gross: "110" }
```

I have tried the following query to no avail:

```
db.reports.aggregate([{$unwind: "$line_items"},{$group: {_id : "$_id", gross: {$sum : {$add: ["$cash", "$miscellaneous"]}}}}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't sum strings, so you'll first need to change the data type of the `cash` and `miscellaneous` fields in your docs to a numeric type.

But once you do that, you can sum them by including the `line_items.` prefix on those fields in your `aggregate` command:

```javascript
db.reports.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$line_items"},
    {$group: {
        _id : "$_id", 
        gross: {$sum : {$add: ["$line_items.cash", "$line_items.miscellaneous"]}}
    }}
]);
```

Output:

```javascript
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "2",
            "gross" : 110
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "1",
            "gross" : 35
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: this is it. I needed to prefix with $line_items. Thanks!